# Apache and ProxyPass proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I would like to implement a kind of a proxy system, where I can type url like this: http://example.com/www.stackoverflow.com and get contents of www.stackoverflow.com returned. What I tried is this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/external/.*
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/external/$1 [NC,R=302,L] 
ProxyPassMatch  /external/([A-Za-z]*)/(.*)  wwww.stackoverflow.com/$1/$2
ProxyPassMatch  /external/(.*)  http://$1/
```

This works fine, but works only for stackoverflow.com because it is hardcoded. Is there some kind of rule so that dynamic URL can work, so I can use http://example.com/yahoo.com ? And yes, if try to hardcode yahoo.com or google.com, instead of rewrite url get automatically redirected to yahoo.com or google.com, what's up with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[P]` flag of `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://$1 [P]
```

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p)

Comment: OK that will work if I do just localhost/stackoverflow.com, content will be returned. However, images won't be loaded because of relative path(for example locahost/data/image.jpg) I don't see how this can be fixed, maybe to rewrite all relative links inside html page?